# How to Inserting Form values into mysql database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to the Codeigniter.How to store the form values in mysql using codeigniter ,Can any one help me...Is there any links Can you provide....
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Doesn't CI have any documentation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me clearify you in an easy way...

This will be your controller

```
class Site extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
$this->load->view('form.php');// loading form view
}

function insert_to_db()
{
$this->load->model('site_model');
$this->site_model->insert_to_db();
$this->load->view('success');//loading success view
}
}
```

This will be your views. Befor creating views go to autoload.php and autoload url helper and database class.
In your config.php set config['base_url'] = "path to your site";
form.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/insert_into_db" method="post">
Field 1 = <input type = 'text' name='f1'>
Field 2 = <input type = 'text' name='f2'>
Field 3 = <input type = 'text' name='f3'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

success.php

```
<b>Your data has been inserted!!!</b>
```

In your model you need to pull those datas of form and insert into db this way

site_model.php

```
class Site_model extends CI_Model
{
function insert_into_db()
{
$f1 = $_POST['f1'];
$f2 = $_POST['f2'];
$f3 = $_POST['f3'];
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES('$f1','$f2','$f3')");
}
}
```

In this case your database has three fields... modify query as per your requirements

Comment: +1 Thanks for answer ..I am trying to running it not showing the any it means showing the blank screen.Can you help me.

Comment: There must be some problem with your configuration.... To use the process above please set the following settings.... In your application/config/autoload.php => $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); $autoload['helper'] = array('url'); If you have not used htaccess or route files then in URL place the full URL for eg. http://baseURL/index.php/controller/function

Comment: Also make sure if you have created your view files.... Atleast the datas must have been inserted into your database... Please check them out. And sorry for the late reply...

Comment: Thanks for reply.i did the thing what ever you mention above,i got the form but when i submit the form it showing  "404 Page Not Found"  and in url it showing   http://localhost/sample/index.php/site/insert_into_db?f1=aaa&f2=bbb&f3=ccc like this. Can you solve my problem...

Comment: i change the route file like this $route['default_controller'] = "Site";

Comment: everything fine but when i click the submit button it passing the values in url inserting the null values in table.. Can you help me..

Comment: finaaly data inserting in table..

Comment: Great.... Sorry I use Stack overflow in around once in two days... So could not reply.... So, the datas are inserting? Great!! Go through the usergiode carefully... You will find everything there... You can also visit net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/ this has a real good CI tutorial

Comment: Thank you.I have anotherdoubt, how to export gridview data to pdf file in php using codeigniter.Can you help me..

Comment: i am unable to update the data can u help me

Comment: sorry bro... I have to search for it... right now I have no idea

Comment: Thank you .i got the solution for exproting the pdf .Do you have idea on updating Can you let me know because i'm unable to update the data...

Comment: Updating? Do you mean updating table of database? If I am right just use $this->db->query("UPDATE tbl_name SET field1 = '..', field2 = '..' WHERE conditions"); There are other ways too... but this is simple for beginners.

Comment: Can you give Clear Please..I tryed but i didn't get .Can you heelp me.

Answer (score 1):

The CodeIgniter manual is pretty helpful.

Take a look at the [Database Quickstart](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Go though the [Database Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html). It has all the functions used to manipulate the database. If you really want to learn codeigniter, take a few hours and go through the [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Comment: @Aadam i read but i didn't get clearly..Can you help me..

Comment: can I see the model/view/controller you have

Comment: i follow the http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/        but i want create a simple form,if i submit that form values store database...

Comment: @Anwar posted a great answer.

Comment: Anwar posted code $this->site_model->insert_to_db(); here this function i didn't get .It showing error "404 Page Not Found" .Can you help me